# Import ES Module to global scope?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to accomplish something like this with ES Modules? (e.g. using a module in the global scope)  I know I could do it with an IIFE or a class...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module">
        import * as util from './util.js'; // defines myfunc()
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        util.myfunc()
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So this doesn't work?

Comment: Correct. It throws an error. So to clarify, my question: am I close and just missing some syntax, or is this not how ES modules are designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I revisited this.  Yes it is possible and it is obvious to me now.

```
<!-- contents of util.js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo')
}
export { foo };
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module">
      import * as util from "./util.js";
      window.util = util
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="util.foo()">foo</button>
  </body>
</html>
```